# Read (dynamic) string from stdin Assembly ARM11

Tags: assembly, arm, raspberry-pi

Consider the following code

```
.bss
    .lcomm num, 20 /* Reserve 20 bytes for local common storage */

.text
.global _start
_start:
    /* read from stdin */
    mov r0, $1  /* Move 1 into r0 register for syscall (file descriptor stdout) */
    ldr r1, =num    /* Load our reserved 20 bytes for the buffer into r1  */
    mov r2, $20     /* Set our max input to 20 bytes  */
    mov r7, #3  /* Load syscall read (3) into r7  */
    swi $0      /* Invoke the system call */

    /* print to stdout */
    mov r0, $1  /* Move 1 into r0 register for syscall (file descriptor stdout) */
    ldr r1, =num    /* Load our now populated buffer into r1  */
    mov r2, $20 /* Set the write output to 20 bytes  */
    mov r7, #4  /* Load syscall write (4) into r7  */
    swi $0      /* Invoke the system call */

    /* exit with 0 exit code */
    mov     r0, $0  /* Set exit code to 0 in register r0 */
    mov     r7, $1  /* Load syscall number into register r7 (1 for exit) */
    swi     $0      /* Invoke the system call */
```

It's clear .lcomm num, 20 is just 20 bytes, and as such bounding the max size of the inputted string to just 20 bytes.

How can I change this code to accept any length of string? (Within reason).

Comment: How would you do it in C? (Why did you tag it with C anyway?)

Comment: The `.bss` is usually the last part of a mapped program image; accessing data after that will probably cause an interrupt, so you'll want to do a system call to ask for more memory, usually called [brk](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/brk.2.html).

Answer (score 0):

The code might be incorrect: you `write` `20` bytes even if the `read` system call returned with a lesser count, as it would if standard input is a smaller file.

Your question is not clear.  Do you wish to read all data available in standard input in one system call and just write it in one chunk to standard output?  Be aware that this is not always possible:

- standard input might be a file larger than available memory.
- standard input might be a device or a pipe for which you cannot know how man bytes can be read before end of file.
- indeed, reading from a pipe will yield limited chunks at a time.  You may need to issue multiple system calls to read all the input.

There might even be other reasons for the system call to fail and require restarting, for instance if a signal interrupts it. look at the man page for `read`.

If you want to implement a simplistic `cat` in assembler, you should at least implement these cases.  Choose a larger buffer size, loop until end of file is detected (`read` returning a 0 byte count), and handle `read` and `write` errors and short counts appropriately.

Tagging `C` is not useless: you should indeed write a C implementation and look at the assembly output for inspiration.